# How to move content of the page slowly down the screen?

Tags: jquery, html, animation

I have a HTML page, and when I mouse over the menu I want that content of the page is moved down so that the menu is not over the page.

**HTML**

```
<div id="move">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.move_dol {
clear: both;
margin-bottom: 180px !important;
}

jQuery('#meni1_over').hover(function(){
jQuery('#move').addClass('move_dol');
});
```

But I want that this `move_dol` is moved slowly. I have tried with `stop` and `animate` function but it's not working.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use jQuery [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to modify the margin-bottom property:

```
jQuery('#meni1_over').hover(function(){
  jQuery('#move').animate({ "margin-bottom": "180px" });
});
```

Or if you want you can use jQuery UI's [addClass](http://jqueryui.com/addClass/) method to animate the addition of your CSS class:

```
jQuery('#meni1_over').hover(function(){
  jQuery('#move').addClass("move_dol", 1000);
});
```

Comment: @Connor Says in his CSS `margin-bottom: 180px !important;`

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with [CSS Transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions)

CSS Transitions

```
.move_dol {
   clear: both;
   margin-top: 180px !important;
   -webkit-transition: margin 1000ms ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: margin 1000ms ease-in-out;
   transition: margin 1000ms ease-in-out;
}
```

jQuery

```
jQuery('#meni1_over').hover(function(){
   jQuery('#move').addClass('move_dol');
});
```